# Pentaho data-integration, add row in text file output

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I have a stupid problem but I cannot go ahead until now...
I have a simple "Table Input" with a query, this query return:

Name, Answers

Alice, 1

Bob, 10

Chris, 7

...

This output is sent to a "Text File Output" and until here all is ok, it wrote a simple txt file with all data.

Now I need to add at the end of this file the sum of all the answers, so the output should be

Name, Answers

Alice, 1

Bob, 10

Chris, 7

TOTAL, 18

I thought it was a simpler thing but I cannot find a solution...

Can anyone help me to find a way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Roy